# Java InputStream with different Object Classes

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, outputstream, fileinputstream

my code has to read in two different Object Types (Bestellung, AKunde) through a ObjectOutputStream and save it in a csv file, which works.
But when i try to read them from the file it doesn't work. 
Here is the code:

OutputStream:

```
LinkedList<Bestellung> bestellListe = verwaltungBestell.getBestellListe();
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

            for (AKunde kunde : kundenliste) {
                outputStream.writeObject(kunde);
            }
            for (Bestellung bestellung : bestellListe) {
                outputStream.writeObject(bestellung);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

InputStream:

```
ArrayList<AKunde> kundenImport = new ArrayList<AKunde>();
ArrayList<Bestellung> bestellungenImport = new ArrayList<Bestellung>();
    boolean cont = true;
    try {

ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(directorie));         
        while (cont) {
            AKunde kunde = null;
            try {
                kunde = (AKunde) objectStream.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            if (kunde != null) {
                kundenImport.add(kunde);
            } else {
                cont = false;
            }
        }
        while (cont) {
            Bestellung bestellung = null;
            try {
                bestellung = (Bestellung) objectStream.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            if (bestellung != null) {
                bestellungenImport.add(bestellung);
            } else {
                cont = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    }
```

But it won't read the "Bestellungen" and won't save them into "bestellungenImport".
Anyone has a solution???

Comment: You need to clarify by providing the exact problem

Comment: What happens when you execute your code?

Comment: When i execute the "AKunden" get added to "kundenImport"  but the "Bestellung objects" don't get adde into "bestellungenImport"

Comment: @luk2302 is explaining why in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code never reaches the `Bestellung` reader part.

You have a false assumption that `kunde =(AKunde)objectStream.readObject();` returns null.

Instead, it throws exception.

Oneway you can do is cast it like @luk2302.

Another way is to add a object count when writing your object stream:

```
outputStream.writeInt(kundenliste.size());
for (AKunde kunde : kundenliste) {
    outputStream.writeObject(kunde);
}

outputStream.writeInt(bestellListe.size());
for (Bestellung bestellung : bestellListe) {
    outputStream.writeObject(bestellung);
}
```

Then replace your `while(cont)` loop with a for each loop:

```
int kundeCount = objectStream.readInt();
for (int i = 0; i < kundeCount; i++) {
   // Read and import kunde
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your logic for reading objects. There are two main issues:

- you never reset `cont` so the second `while` loop will never do anything
- even if you did that you would always skip the first `Bestellung` since it was already read when the second loop is reached

I would propose something along the lines of:

```
Object object = objectStream.readObject();
if (object instanceof AKunde) {
    kundenImport.add((AKunde) object);    
} else if (object instanceof Bestellung) {
    bestellungenImport.add((Bestellung) object);
} else {
    // something else was read
}
```

You simply need to loop over this code and add proper error handling where needed.

Comment: So i implemented your if clause but still the "Bestellungen" won't get added to the bestellungenImport list.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, you change the way you write your objects to `ObjectOutputStream` in the first place:

Directly write the `kundenListe` and `bestellListe` objects, so you dont't have to worry about types or number of elements when reading the objects again. Your stream of object then always contains two objects, the two lists.

```
// use try-with-resources if you're on Java 7 or newer
try (ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
    // write the complete list of objects
    outputStream.writeObject(kundenliste);
    outputStream.writeObject(bestellListe);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //TODO proper exception handling
}
```

Then you could read it just like that:

```
ArrayList<AKunde> kundenImport = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Bestellung> bestellungenImport = new ArrayList<>();

//again try-with-resources
try (ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {
    kundenImport.addAll((List) inputStream.readObject());
    bestellungenImport.addAll((List) inputStream.readObject());
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException  e) { //multi-catch, if Java 7 or newer
    e.printStackTrace(); //TODO proper exception handling
}
```

Further reads:

- [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
- [Catching Multiple Exception Types (...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)